# Jquery Hide header at first and show it on scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here’s a demo page.
https://codyhouse.co/demo/full-screen-pop-out-navigation/index.html

How to hide the header when the screen is on the top of the page, and it will only show on scroll up

Comment: See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to So. Please visit the [help] and take the [tour] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Show effort and code HERE

Comment: What exactly are you asking ? you have a header that disappears when scrolling and comes back when scrolling up

Answer (score 0):

hi try following...

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var _hideVal = 50; //You can change this value...
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > _hideVal) 
   {
       $('.header-holder').fadeIn();
   } 
   else
   {
       $('.header-holder').fadeOut();
   }
});
```